# Understanding tomcat's access logs for aborted or timeout requests

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat

This might be a very ignorant and stupid question ,but please bear with me.

I understand that every request made to any URL behind Tomcat is logged by Tomcat in access logs. I have a Spring Boot REST API running behind Tomcat .What I want to understand is that if some other app tries to access our REST API and aborts the request in between OR it has set a read timeout of say 5 sec, and my server fails to respond within that time frame,then will such request be logged in the access logs ?

Answer (score 0):

It should.

But there was at least [one bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58702) that caused the access logs to be skipped when a client aborts, in the following Tomcat versions:

- 9.0.0.M1 and earlier
- 8.0.30 and earlier
- 7.0.67 and earlier